# Pytest-mock not patching imported function in class module

Tags: pytest, pytest-mock

The pytest-mock patching does not work as expected. My code:

`utils.py`:

```py
def my_func():
    return 42
```

`classes.py`:

```py
from utils import my_func

class MyClass:
    def class_method(self):
        return my_func()
```

`test_classes.py`:

```py
import pytest
from classes import MyClass

def test_myclass(mocker):
    mocker.patch("utils.my_func", return_value=21)
    assert MyClass().class_method() == 21
```

This fails, the return is `42` instead of `21`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is to change the patching within the test. Instead of

```py
mocker.patch("utils.my_func", return_value=21)
```

write

```py
mocker.patch("classes.my_func", return_value=21)
```

because of this line in `classes.py`: `from .utils import my_func`.

Comment: thank you for this answer! this can be really counterintuitive especially for those newer to writing unit tests